# Transform xml with xslt to group nodes preserving comments

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlstarlet

I have a quite simple xml which I want to rearrange using xmlstarlet.

Example:

```xml
<myXml description="example 1">

    <!-- Comment XXX -->
    <randomNodeX>
        <randomSubNode1>value1</randomSubNode1>
        <randomSubNode2>value2</randomSubNode2>
    </randomNodeX>

    <!-- Comment YYY1 -->
    <!-- Comment YYY2 -->
    <randomNodeY attribute1="value3" attribute2="value4"/> 

    <!-- Comment ZZZ -->
    <randomNodeZ attribute1="value5" attribute0="value6">
        <randomSubNode3 attribute3="value7" attribute4="value8"/>
    </randomNodeZ>

    <!-- Comment for node1 first occurrence -->
    <node1 attribute1="value9" attribute5="value10" attribute6="value11"/>

    <!-- Comment for node2 first occurrence -->
    <node2 attribute1="value12" attribute7="value13" attribute8="value14">
        <subNode21 attributeX="value15"/>
        <subNode22 attributeY="value16" attributeZ="value17"/>
    </node2>

    <!-- Comment for node3 first occurrence -->
    <node3 attribute1="value18" attribute9="value19">
        <subNode31 attributeW="value20"/>
    </node3>

    <!-- Comment for node1 second occurrence -->
    <node1 attribute1="value21" attribute5="value22" attribute6="value23"/>

    <!-- Comment for node3 second occurrence -->
    <node3 attribute1="value24" attribute9="value25">
        <subNode31 attributeW="value26"/>
    </node3>

    <!-- Comment for node2 second occurrence -->
    <node2 attribute1="value27" attribute7="value28" attribute8="value29">
        <subNode21 attributeX="value30"/>
        <subNode22 attributeY="value31" attributeZ="value32"/>
    </node2>
</myXml>
```

I want to rearrange the xml so that all node1, node2 and node3 elements appear together with their respective comments. Besides, I want to keep the rest of the document and comments **without having to know which tags are present**. I mean, there can be other tags in the xml apart from node1, node2 and node3 which I want to keep at the begining of the document (comments included).

Expected result:

```xml
<myXml description="example 1">

  <!-- Comment XXX -->
  <randomNodeX>
    <randomSubNode1>value1</randomSubNode1>
    <randomSubNode2>value2</randomSubNode2>
  </randomNodeX>

  <!-- Comment YYY1 -->
  <!-- Comment YYY2 -->
  <randomNodeY attribute1="value3" attribute2="value4"/>

  <!-- Comment ZZZ -->
  <randomNodeZ attribute1="value5" attribute0="value6">
    <randomSubNode3 attribute3="value7" attribute4="value8"/>
  </randomNodeZ>

  <!-- Comment for node1 first occurrence -->
  <node1 attribute1="value9" attribute5="value10" attribute6="value11"/>

  <!-- Comment for node1 second occurrence -->
  <node1 attribute1="value21" attribute5="value22" attribute6="value23"/>

  <!-- Comment for node2 first occurrence -->
  <node2 attribute1="value12" attribute7="value13" attribute8="value14">
    <subNode21 attributeX="value15"/>
    <subNode22 attributeY="value16" attributeZ="value17"/>
  </node2>

  <!-- Comment for node2 second occurrence -->
  <node2 attribute1="value27" attribute7="value28" attribute8="value29">
    <subNode21 attributeX="value30"/>
    <subNode22 attributeY="value31" attributeZ="value32"/>
  </node2>

  <!-- Comment for node3 first occurrence -->
  <node3 attribute1="value18" attribute9="value19">
    <subNode31 attributeW="value20"/>
  </node3>

  <!-- Comment for node3 second occurrence -->
  <node3 attribute1="value24" attribute9="value25">
    <subNode31 attributeW="value26"/>
  </node3>
</myXml>
```

For now I have done it using this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::node1|self::node2|self::node3|self::comment())]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node1"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node2"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node3"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="randomNodeX|randomNodeY|randomNodeZ|node1|node2|node3">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::comment()[generate-id(following-sibling::*[1])=generate-id(current())]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that I have to specify all random tags (randomNodeX, randomNodeY, ...) which are present in the xml.

Is there a way to do this without knowing the tags present apart from node1, node2 and node3 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="my-comments" match="comment()" use="generate-id(following-sibling::*[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/myXml">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::node1 or self::node2 or self::node3)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node1"/>        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node2"/>        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node3"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('my-comments', generate-id())"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

In **XSLT 2.0** this could be streamlined to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="my-comments" match="comment()" use="generate-id(following-sibling::*[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/myXml">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="my-nodes" select="node1, node2, node3" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except $my-nodes, $my-nodes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('my-comments', generate-id())"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice solution Michael. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of an `except` operation in XPath 2 available as the `except` operator, in XPath 1 in XSLT 1 perhaps expressed as

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="node1 | node2 | node3"/>
      <xsl:variable name="trailers" select="$nodes | $nodes/preceding-sibling::comment()[1]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[count(. | $trailers) > count($trailers)]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$trailers"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

This assumes all your `node1`, `node2` and `node3` elements are having exactly one preceding sibling comment node.

I am not quite sure, however, why you didn't just use `match="/*/*"` instead of `match="randomNodeX|randomNodeY|randomNodeZ|node1|node2|node3"`.

Comment: You are right. It's enough to use match="/*/*". Thank you Martin!

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0+ solution:

I would start with a grouping operation that groups elements with their "associated" comments, so that

```
  <!-- Comment ZZZ -->
  <randomNodeZ attribute1="value5" attribute0="value6">
    <randomSubNode3 attribute3="value7" attribute4="value8"/>
  </randomNodeZ>
```

becomes

```
  <group>
    <!-- Comment ZZZ -->
    <randomNodeZ attribute1="value5" attribute0="value6">
      <randomSubNode3 attribute3="value7" attribute4="value8"/>
    </randomNodeZ>
  </group>
```

and then in phase 2, group the groups according to the contained element name (dropping the `group` wrapper at the same time).

In your example every element is preceded by one or more "associated" comments, but can we rely on that always being the case? To be a bit more tolerant of input variations, we could say that a group starts on any comment or element that isn't immediately preceded by a comment. If we assume whitespace has been stripped using xsl:strip-space, we can do the first grouping with

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="child::node()"
 group-starting-with="(comment()|*)[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::comment()]">
  <group><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

and the second is

```
   <xsl:for-each-group select="group" group-by="name(*[1])">
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/child::node()"/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
```

but you might want to re-inject some whitespace.

Comment: Your solution works fine too. Thank you so much Michael!